# type object 'Espece' has no attribute 'esp_id'

Tags: python, django

Hello I 'am trying to learn how to use django . I m trying to save into my database from a formu but in each time i got this error

> Request Method:   POST Request URL:   localhost:8000/espece/ Django
>   Version:  1.6.2 Exception Type:   AttributeError Exception Value:  type
>   object 'Espece' has no attribute 'esp_id' Exception
>   Location: C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py
>   in value_from_object, line 560 Python
>   Executable:   C:\Python33\python.exe Python Version:  3.3.4

```
from django.db import models

class Espece(models.Model):
    esp_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    esp_nom=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    esp_type=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    esp_freq=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    esp_latin=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    esp_vul=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    esp_suivie=models.BooleanField(null=False)
    esp_old_id=models.IntegerField()
```

'
views.py

```
def espece(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=EspeceForm(request.POST,instance=Espece)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form=EspeceForm()
    from django.template import RequestContext
    return render(request, 'oiseaux_suivi.html', {'form': form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()
 urlpatterns = patterns('polls.views',
                   url(r'^accueil/$','home'),
                   url(r'^article/(\d+)/$', 'view_article'),
                   url(r'^redirection/$', 'view_redirection'),
                  # url(r'^$', 'tpl'),
                   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                   url(r'^polls/$', 'index'),
                   url(r'^oiseau_suiv/$','oiseau_suiv'),
                   url(r'^espece/$','espece'),
                 #  url(r'^success/$','sucess'),
                   )
```

Can anyone help me please

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492325/editing-the-form-in-django-creates-new-instance for example.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the line `form=EspeceForm(request.POST,instance=Espece)`

Your are passing the "class Espece" when you really need a instance of this class.